# Moderator error - Comment must have a valid owner

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error when converting answer to comment on question of deleted user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78453/error-when-converting-answer-to-comment-on-question-of-deleted-user)

I attempted to migrate an answer which should have been a comment on a previous answer. However when I attempted it, I received an error

> "Comment must have a valid owner"

The possible issue is that the user who answered the question is no longer on the site.

The answer in question is [Steeping grain time](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1316/steeping-grain-time/1405#1405)

It should be a comment on answer [Steeping grain time](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1316/steeping-grain-time/1378)

Repro steps:

1. Click on Mod -> Convert To Comment
2. Replace the ID with "[Steeping grain time](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1316/steeping-grain-time/1378)"
3. Click Submit
4. Profit

Am I doing this wrong? Or is this a bug?

Comment: The person who made the answers doesn't exist anymore.  I'd just nuke them; they aren't answers and wouldn't add much as comments.

Comment: Just for reference http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/25307/520 is an instance of a bad answer that would make a decent comment but can not be converted because the astro.se user does not have a physics.se account.